# React Native flatlist, unable to load view from the start

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-flatlist

```
                      <FlatList
                        data={data}                        
                        inverted
                        horizontal 
                        renderItem={({ item }) => {

                            if ( item.type == 'video') {
                                return(
                                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.videoView}>
                                        <View>
                                            <Image 
                                                source={require('./assets/thumbnail.png')}
                                                style={styles.thumbnail}
                                            />
                                            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>  
                                );
                            }
                        }}
                        
                      />
```

The flatlist is getting the from a JSON file from the internet, but when ever I load the app on the phone, the list takes me to the first element of the JSON file(bottom of the list), but I want to see the last element of the JSON file(top of the list) when I load the app.

Comment: Why don't you try `data.reverse()`?

Comment: I did, but the id=1 from the JSON file is the first element in the list, but I want it to be the last. Which is happening when Im using the it like this, I want to have the view loaded at the start of flatlist id=30, but right now Im getting it loaded from the last of the list id=1

Comment: So why is reverse not working for you? If you reverse it, the one that was previously the first element should be the last

Comment: I don't know, reverse doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) could reverse your data then renders it. You can do it before render

Comment: nothing happens when I do that. If I understand you correctly you want me to do this 'data={data.reverse()}